# How to get and set cultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7, cultureinfo

I am using Umbraco 7 with a user control on a page. I have built some resx files for France (for example but many other countries)

On page load i have the below code

```
var cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

My template is set with `href lang="en"` as the default. Cultures and hostnames is set as `inherited` but i can never set the culture to what i want?

Example

My site structure is

site.com/parent/child

When the user arrives to the child page which contains the control, I want to translate the data.

I want to test data for France. I execute the code above on page load which is hard coded to France (I can change this to be dynamic later) for testing only.

Currently I load the data by France, which displays the French data as it is saved with fr-FR in the database.

The problem I face is my resx file contains text for the French language and that never displays against the controls. It appears in English.

So the markup code for a label text is similar to

```
<asp:label runat="server" id="lblSayHello" Text="<% Resources:Resource SayHello%>" />
```

So me setting and hard coding the language on page load I was expecting to see Bonjour but instead I see hello (coming from the default Resource.resx file). Bonjour is the text I have against the fr-FR resx file which doesn't display.

How could i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings tab and in the languages folder add the new culture/language.

Then set the culture/hostname for your template, or the template its inheriting its culture/hostnames from.

Comment: I have added the languages i.e. France and Germany. How do i set this within the template from code-behind? Ideally i have one user control that i would like to use for both countries so when they arrive to site.com/parent/child the child page would load the data by country? Thanks

Comment: Note sure how feasible that is with umbraco 7, have a look at a plug in call Vorto. Failing that how would you input content for both languages just so I can understand what you're after.

Comment: The data for each country would be stored in database. I am storing the data with the country language i.e. de-DE fr-FR what I would like to do is when the user arrives they select the country by a button/drop-down on the parent page (see previous comment). This would land them on the child page. So I can load the data from the database but in order to display some of the headings for each language I'm storing them in the resx file. It's this info I can't load? Hope this makes some sense?

Comment: Ahh I see, im not sure setting the culture is the right way to go with this. As it's setting it serverside and you could have multiple users viewing the same child page in different languages. I think storing the language in session or a cookie and then reading the data in a controller after checking the users session or cookie

Comment: thanks for that, I could try adding it to session. I added it to page load just to test it but if it worked I can change it to session. The problem I'm facing is that when I have it set on page load as above it doesn't pick up the French translation from my resx file it defaults to English. If I could get it working with the French language I could then change it accordingly? Thanks

Comment: One thing to note about using session is if its on a load balancer remember to enable sticky sessions. How are you trying to set it to use French?